# How to Resolve Type Mismatch Runtime "error code 13" MS Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have created two simple VBA code modules in MS Access.

1) This one works great -

```
Private Sub IFLType_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
If [ProductType] <> "IFL" Then
  If [IFLType] <> IsNotNull Then
    MsgBox ("IFLType only valid for ProductType = IFL")
  End If
End If
End Sub
```

2) This one produces Type Mismatch Runtime error #13 and the debugger highlights the line with the "Or" logic -

```
Private Sub ProductDue_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
If [ProductType] <> "IFL" Or "3-TIER IPRN" Or "CD IPRN" Then
  If [ProductDue] <> IsNotNull Then
    MsgBox ("ProductDue only valid for ProductType = IFL, 3-TIER IPRN, and CD IPRN")
  End If
End If
End Sub
```

The only significant difference between these is the "Or" logic. Any ideas for how to write the "Or" logic and make this work?

Comment: That _IsNotNull_ is spooky. Try: `If Not IsNull([IFLType]) Then`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to write the complete or statement, like this:

```
If [ProductType] <> "IFL" Or [ProductType] <> "3-TIER IPRN" Or [ProductType] <>  "CD IPRN" Then ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to [operator precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/operator-precedence) in VBA, comparison operators (such as `<>`) will be evaluated before logical operators (such as `Or`); as such, you will need to include a comparison operator between each of your logical operators, i.e.:

```
Private Sub ProductDue_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    If [ProductType] <> "IFL" Or [ProductType] <> "3-TIER IPRN" Or [ProductType] <> "CD IPRN" Then
        If [ProductDue] <> IsNotNull Then
            MsgBox ("ProductDue only valid for ProductType = IFL, 3-TIER IPRN, and CD IPRN")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

However, based on the message you are reporting to the user, I believe you will actually require `And` operators in place of `Or` operators, since, if `[ProductType]` is equal to `"3-TIER IPRN"` then the `Or` statement will return `True` for `[ProductType] <> "IFL"` and the test expression for the `If` statement will be validated.

Therefore, I believe your test should be:

```
Private Sub ProductDue_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    If [ProductType] <> "IFL" And [ProductType] <> "3-TIER IPRN" And [ProductType] <> "CD IPRN" Then
        If [ProductDue] <> IsNotNull Then
            MsgBox ("ProductDue only valid for ProductType = IFL, 3-TIER IPRN, and CD IPRN")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Or alternatively (and maybe more readable):

```
Private Sub ProductDue_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    If Not ([ProductType] = "IFL" Or [ProductType] = "3-TIER IPRN" Or [ProductType] = "CD IPRN") Then
        If [ProductDue] <> IsNotNull Then
            MsgBox ("ProductDue only valid for ProductType = IFL, 3-TIER IPRN, and CD IPRN")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

You could also combine your second test expression with the first to avoid the nested `If` statement, i.e.:

```
Private Sub ProductDue_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    If [ProductDue] <> IsNotNull And (Not ([ProductType] = "IFL" Or [ProductType] = "3-TIER IPRN" Or [ProductType] = "CD IPRN")) Then
        MsgBox ("ProductDue only valid for ProductType = IFL, 3-TIER IPRN, and CD IPRN")
    End If
End Sub
```